# Cells.find error 91

Tags: vba

I have problems with this code. I tried to figure it what is wrong with this code, but cannot find the solution

```
 Sub RDB_Worksheet_To_PDF()
        Dim FileName As String
        Dim PONumber As String
        Dim FolderPath As String

 PONumber = Sheets("Purchase Order with Sales Tax").Cells(8, 6).Value

    If ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Count > 1 Then
        MsgBox "There is more then one sheet selected," & vbNewLine & _
               "be aware that every selected sheet will be published"
    End If
'Call the function with the correct arguments
    FileName = RDB_Create_PDF(ActiveSheet, FolderPath & PONumber, True, True)

    If FileName <> FolderPath & PONumber Then
        'Ok, you find the PDF where you saved it
        'You can call the mail macro here if you want
        MsgBox "Sweet! The PO has been saved as a PDF." & vbNewLine & _
               "Click on the PO Number in the PO Number WorkSheet to view."
    Else
        MsgBox "Not possible to create the PDF, possible reasons:" & vbNewLine & _
               "Microsoft Add-in is not installed" & vbNewLine & _
               "There is no PO number selected" & vbNewLine & _
               "The path to Save the file in is not correct" & vbNewLine & _
               "You didn't want to overwrite the existing PDF if it exist"
    End If

    Sheets("PO Number").Select
    Range("A1").Select
```

I get the error message 91 in this part

```
**Cells.Find(What:=PONumber, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate**
```

Is it because I did not use .activate or I did not use set = ?
Please let me know what I need to do.

Cheers

Comment: where is the rest of the code? Incomplete Info it seems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you are trying to find the cell AND activate it at the same time, which will prompt you the error mentioned if nothing is found.  You could try find it first then activate:

```
set smvar = Cells.Find(What:=PONumber, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
    :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
    False, SearchFormat:=False)  
if not smvar is Nothing then smvar.activate
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment but i get the other error message 9 in this part                                                               PONumber = Sheets("Purchase Order with Sales Tax").Cells(8, 6).Value

Comment: Is it the same cells.find error 91, or run time error '9'? If it is error 9 check your sheet's name (space / etc).  Also I assume the code sits in a "module".  Also please mention all the errors you have

Comment: I saw cells.find error 91 before, after I changed the code to what you suggested set smavar = and then I have got error 9 in Sheets("Purchase Order with Sales Tax").Cells(8, 6).Value

Comment: Oh you mean another error comes up after the first is fixed.  Did you try checking your sheet name?

Comment: Hello Alex, thank u for your help, my code is working fine now. I do not see any error messages. I do not know why I got the error 9 before.

Comment: Glad to know.  If you don't mind please accept the answer so people know it's solved, thanks