# VBA that finds duplicate information hitting Run-time error 91

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to use a form to create a row that stringes together two values in a concat using a string. Upon clicking the finish button the macro checks several values to determine if it can place in the information. One of these rules I am trying to set is detecting if the string/value already exists.

```
ID = txtStory.Value & "." & txtTask.Value

If Range("A7:A98").Cells.Find(what:=ID, LookAt:=xlWhole) > 0 Then
MsgBox "Story ID already exists.", vbExclamation, "Duplicate Found"
Exit Sub
End If
```

The code operates correctly when the information violates the rule. However, if the result is false (the values are not duplicate with anything in the column) then I receive **"Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set"**

What needs to be adjusted to fix the issue?

Comment: Need to see the whole code to be able to help you. This is not the part that you have an issue with. When you don't have duplicates you go pass that `End If` and somewhere there you have a bug.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cells.find error 91](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26243490/cells-find-error-91)

Comment: Here's the reference for the range.find method https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx. Range.find returns a Range object, or Nothing (a VBA keyword) if no match is found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Find` returns a `Range` object reference. When nothing matches the criteria, the function returns `Nothing` - a null reference.

This is indeed very very close to the linked would-be-duplicate, with the following nuance - this:

```
Range("...").Cells.Find(...) > 0
```

Is really doing this:

```
Range("...").Cells.Find(...).Value > 0
```

You're **implicitly** calling into the `Range` object's *default member*, which points to its `Value`.

It's that implicit member call that's throwing runtime error 91, because `Find` returned `Nothing` so you have no object to get a value from, to perform the `> 0` comparison.

The solution *for the error 91* is, as in the linked Q&A, to first verify that `Find` returns a valid object reference.

The solution to avoid similar bugs in the future and in many other circumstances, is to avoid implicit default member calls - i.e., write code that means what it says and that says what it means.

```
Set result = Range("...").Find(...)
If Not result Is Nothing Then
    '.Find call was successful
    If result.Value > 0 Then   '<< explicit Range.Value member call
        '...
    End If
Else
    '.Find call failed
End If
```

Note that the `.Cell` member call is redundant.

Comment: Thanks a ton! Shout out Rich Holton as well, the link provided a similar andswer and pointed me in the right direction.