# Searching a string in all worksheets and copy the selected column in Another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am a rookie to VBA coding and I'm working on a project to search a string (e.g. 1207_Stackoverflow_com) from all worksheet of a workbook lets call it WB1 and select the column which the code searches and paste it to another workbook say WB2. Every time the code searches the row containing the string will copy the column to the next sheet in WB2.  I tried but code is giving an error. All help is appreciated. Below is the code which I construct (I know it is a crude code, feel free to use your style of coding to educate me)

```
Sub SearchAndPaste()

    Dim WB1 As Workbook, WB2 As Workbook
    Dim myRng As Variant, mFind As Variant
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim Col1

    Set WB1 = Workbooks.Open("Path of workbook")

    WB2 = ThisWorkbook
    mDate = WB2.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J3").Value


    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
    Set rng = WB2.Worksheets.Range("A2:CJ2")
    Cells(myRng.Row, myRng.Column).Select
    Col1 = Selection.Column

    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        ' Find first instance on sheet
        Set myRng = rng.Find(What:=Str(mFind), After:=sh.Cells(1, 1), _
            LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        If Not cl Is Nothing Then
            ' if found, remember location
            Cells(myRng.Row, myRng.Column).Select
            Col1 = Selection.Column
            ' Copy column
            Do

                ' find next instance
                Set Col1 = sh.Cells.FindNext(After:=cl)
                ' repeat until back where we started
            Loop Until FirstFound = Col1.Address
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Runtime error 91 by any chance? What is `cl`? It's not declared anywhere. Specify `Option Explicit` at the top of every module, and declare all your variables. I suspect you meant to check whether `myRnd` is `Nothing`, not `cl`... whatever that is.

Comment: [Speaking of searching...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26243490/cells-find-error-91)

Comment: @Mat's Mug `cl` was mistyped, the code is this:                                 
                               `Set Col1 = sh.Cells.FindNext(After:=Col1)`