# excel VBA .find error

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to do a simple find method. I know "170" exists at Z2. My error reads

Run-time error '91':

Object variable or With block variable not set

```
Dim cutRef as Range

Worksheets("Sun").Activate
With Rows(2)
Set cutRef = .Find("170")
End With

MsgBox cutRef.Address
```

I have no clue what i am doing wrong. Thanks for your help.

Comment: A lot, start by not relying on `.Activate` and always define by `ThisWorkbook`.  What line is this occurring on?  The `MsgBox` or the `Set cutRef`?

Comment: I need activate because this is ran off a button on another sheet. i am getting the error as MsgBox because cutRef is reading as nothing

Comment: That's not a reason to `Activate`. Qualify `Rows` with the worksheet object instead. You're getting an error because `.Find` doesn't *find* that you're making it look for. `Find` returns `Nothing` when it doesn't find anything, and your code assumes it always does.

Comment: Gah, wrong dupe, sorry. Try [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26243490/1188513). Or [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11984404/1188513). Or [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29102052/1188513).

Comment: Always check if your Methods have returned `Nothing`, especially with the shakier application methods like `.Find`

Comment: As for *why .Find doesn't find the "170"*, there's nothing anyone on this site can do without seeing the actual worksheet. Good luck!